Closed form for norm of idèle in Neukirch
at page 371 ((ii) of (2.3)) of Neukirch, algebraic number theory, it is said :
"If $L/K$ is embedded into the Galois extension $M/K$ and if $G=G(M/K)$ and $H=G(M/L)$, then one has for $\alpha \in I_{L}$: $N_{L/K}(\alpha)=\Pi_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \alpha$."
Where $I_{L}$ is the idèle group of $L$, $L$ is a finite extension of $K$ while $N_{L/K}$ is the norm of idèles.
If some want the definition of the norm of idèles, one way is to put :
$N_{L/K}(\alpha)_p=\Pi_{\beta / p}N_{L_{\beta}/K_p}(\alpha_\beta)$
Where $p$ denotes the places of $K$ and $\beta$ denotes the places of $L$ that lie over $p$.
I don't understand how to get to the closed form with the product over cosets, is it even true?
EDIT :
More precisely, This is what I'm getting :
$(\Pi_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \alpha)_{p}=\Pi_{\beta}\Pi_{\sigma \in G/H} (\sigma \alpha_{\beta})$
Meanwhile :
$N_{L/K}(\alpha)_p=\Pi_{\beta}N_{L_{\beta}/K_p}(\alpha_\beta)=\Pi_{\beta}\Pi_{\sigma \in G_{\beta}/H_{\beta}}(\sigma\alpha_\beta)$
Where $G_{\beta}$ denotes the decomposition group of $\beta$ and $H_{\beta}$ is the intersection of the decomposition group and H. It doesn't match sadly. One way to fix the issue would be to declare that Neukirch's notation of the product over the cosets isn't a product over the $\beta$, but this would be ill defined because we don't generally have $\sigma(\alpha_\beta)=\alpha_{(\sigma \beta)}$.

This is not really about ideles. Do you know the norm of $\alpha \in L$ over $K$ is the product of its conjugates? Do you know that all the conjugates of $\alpha$ lie in the splitting field and hence lie in any Galois extension $M/K$ containing $L$? Do you see that if $H=\mathrm{Gal}(M/L)$ then any element $\sigma h \in \sigma H$ acts the same on $\alpha$? Do you see that if $\sigma  \in \sigma H$ and $\tau \in \tau H$ are different cosets then $\sigma \alpha \ne \tau \alpha$? Do you see how the conjugates of $\alpha$ are in bijection with left cosets of $H$? Can you answer  your own question?

Yes I do know that, but the problem with idèles is that it is not necessarily true that $\sigma(\alpha_{\beta})=\alpha_{(\sigma\beta)}$ with $\beta$ and $\sigma\beta$ two places of $L$

There's a norm map $N: L\rightarrow K$ on fields, and it can be understood in
terms of $L\subset M$ and the action of $G$. You say you understand this. Now you need to understand the norm map
$$N: L \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p \rightarrow K \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p$$
If you don't see why this is given by the same formula  perhaps you are confused how $G$ acts on $M \otimes \mathbf{Q}_p$. Think about the case $K= \mathbf{Q}$ and then consider $L$ a quadratic extension and then $L$
a non-Galois cubic field and it should be clear. If not, give your detailed working here and someone else might help you.
